# How to set breakpoints in library in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on osx,

My program loads an external library and I would like to set breakpoints there  too, both the main app as the .so file are compiled with the -g flag, but when I try to set a breakpoint it's never hit.

In the developer console I do see: ..../gamelibrary.so'. Symbols loaded.

I have the feeling I ought to put something in launch.json for it to work, but I don't know what.

thanks!